# `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_nlu'` error

Tags: installation, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am starting with building a chatbot using rasa. I have followed the installation guide of [rasa documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/)

I have installed rasa using

```
pip install rasa
```

I can import rasa using `import rasa` and `rasa.__version__` gives me a output `1.10.0` but when I try to import `rasa-nlu` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_nlu'` error. I am working on windows and seen few suggestions that Visual Studio Installer is also required for windows set up. Why is Visual Studio Installer required, or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are facing the legit error - I would suggest you move to Linux for easy work with rasa.
I have faced the same issue just like you and when worked with Ubuntu to be more specific the work goes way to smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You should install rasa-nlu

```
pip install rasa-nlu
```

https://pypi.org/project/rasa-nlu/

Comment: doesn't `rasa` include everything? any idea why visual studio installer is required?

Comment: you try check this video, may be help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAb8Ei7dQjc&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve visual c++ error, follow the steps in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136595/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-require.html

To remove module not found rasa-nlu error, do `pip install rasa-nlu` and install all other dependencies which you will encounter during installation of rasa-nlu.